# Django type error: 'unicode' object is not callable

Tags: python, django, unicode

I am trying to build a message tagging application, and I've been encountering this error message.

```
Internal Server Error: /
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py", line 115, in get_response
    response = callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
TypeError: 'unicode' object is not callable
```

I've been getting this error constantly, no matter what I tried, including deleting the whole models.py file.

Below are some snippets of the files.

models.py

```
class Tag(models.Model):
    tag_name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    date_created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
    return self.tag_name
```

views.py

```
def multiple(request):
    qs = Tag.objects.all()

    template = loader.get_template('multiple.html')
    context = RequestContext(request, {
        'qs': qs,
    })
```

I'm not sure how to fix this problem, especially because it's not actually referencing any of the files that I've created.

Comment: Please, also show your url configuration

Comment: And the template as well :)

Comment: urlpatterns = patterns('app.views',
    url(r'^$',             'multiple.'),
) There you go.

Comment: Can you add the requested info in your question body please? I'm pretty sure the problem is in your template.

Answer (score 2):

I think this is your problem:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('app.views', url(r'^$', 'multiple.'), )
                                                        ^
```

See the dot? That breaks looking up the view function.

Comment: @user2857014 You can select the 'tick' making it green to accept a (most) correct answer.